# create a datasource from a list

Tags: c#

Im iterating a list and getting hold of 2 fields "Name" and "Url"

i want to extract these fields and use them to create a datasource

I want to databind these to a dropdownList

```
DropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";
DropDownList.DataValueField = "Url";
```

how can I create a datasource based on this list? 
then do the above, then databind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you have an list item named MyListItem and MyListItem has two properties Name and Url, you can bind a list of MyListItem like that :

```
List<MyListItem> dataSource = new List<MyListItem>();

MyListItem item1 = new MyListItem();
item1.Name = "Name 1";
item1.Url = "Url 1";
dataSource.Add(item1);

MyListItem item2 = new MyListItem();
item2.Name = "Name 2";
item2.Url = "Url 2";
dataSource.Add(item2);

dropDownList.DataSource = dataSource;
dropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";
dropDownList.DataValueField = "Url";
dropDownList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you using .NET 3.5?

Then go with an anonymous type, like:

```
var ds = from item in items
select new { Name = item.Name, Url = item.Url };

dropdownlist.DataSource = ds;
...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
    table.Add("Key1", "val1"); //Build this table using the list you have.

    DropDownList.DataSource = table;
    DropDownList.DataMember = "Key";
    DropDownList.DataTextField = "Value";
    DropDownList.DataBind();
```